# Text Direction of NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I want a NSTextField with text direction as

[image]

how could I achieve this? thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: if its static, did you try to rotate of `NSTextField` ?

Comment: nop i didn't try rotation

Comment: ok, I add answer @Awais, hope it helps

Comment: hey @Awais, did it worked?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Choose orientation to `Vertical` and then set text.

The input must be look like that.

[image]

I missed the `NSTextField`points so did it with `NSTextView` thanks to comment of @Willeke.

`Cocoa` framework has some points to rotate UI components.

For your `NSTextField`

`myTextField.rotate(byDegrees: 90)`

set your width & height carefully.

Comment: `NSTextView` instead of `NSTextField`?

Comment: thanks for comment @Willeke, I get as `NSTextView` so edited it additionally

Answer (score 0):

I rotate the NSTextField

```
nameTF.rotate(byDegrees: 270)
```

calculate the new height and width of NSTextField

```
let newHeight = nameTF.bestHeight(for: nameTF.stringValue, width: nameTF.frame.width)
let newWidth = nameTF.bestWidth(for: nameTF.stringValue, height: nameTF.frame.height)
```

set the new frame of NSTextField

```
 nameTF.frame = CGRect(x: nameTF.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.height - newWidth - 30, width: newHeight, height: newWidth)
```

used the extension of NSTextField

```
extension NSTextField {
func bestHeight(for text: String, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
      stringValue = text
      let height = cell!.cellSize(forBounds: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height

      return height
  }

  func bestWidth(for text: String, height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
      stringValue = text
      let width = cell!.cellSize(forBounds: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)).width

      return width
  }
```

}